GitHub Actions PreCommit FatalError: git failed
I have a task to move CI/CD from Gitlab to GitHub Actions and there is one last obstacle I encounter. PreCommit library is not working.
Everything worked fine in gitlab and that is why I have no idea what could I change
My Code
name: CI Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  pre-commit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: python:3.11
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Print current directory
      run: pwd

    - name: Set up Python 3.11
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.11
          
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Check Git version
      run: git --version
      
    - name: Initialize Git
      run: git init  # Optional step if needed

    - name: Cache pre-commit hooks
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/.cache/pre-commit
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-precommit-${{ hashFiles('.pre-commit-config.yaml') }}

    - name: Install pre-commit
      run: pip install pre-commit

    - name: Run pre-commit with debug
      run: pre-commit run --all-files


Error
Run pre-commit run --all-files
  pre-commit run --all-files
  shell: sh -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /__t/Python/3.11.9/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /__t/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib
An error has occurred: FatalError: git failed. Is it installed, and are you in a Git repository directory?
Check the log at /github/home/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log


Running inside a container is causing an issue. Container runs as root and all file system is owned by root. As a result git is unable to operate. Removing container works for me with this workflow:
name: pre-commit

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  pre-commit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python 3.11
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.11

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

      - name: Cache pre-commit hooks
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/pre-commit
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-precommit-${{ hashFiles('.pre-commit-config.yaml') }}

      - name: Install pre-commit
        run: python -m pip install pre-commit

      - name: Run pre-commit with debug
        run: pre-commit run --all-files

and this .pre-commit-config.yaml:
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v1.2.3
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace


I ran this inside python:3.11 cointainer because in my gitlab script I used image: python:3.10, and 3.11 because 3.10 does not work in GitHub Actions.
I removed git init and I get the same error

It worked for me, I completely skipped this comment about container.
After removing this code works. Thanks !
